# Photos Look "Washed Out" when attached

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, photos, attachments

I have Galaxy sIII and now when I attach photos, regardless if I do so by txt, Facebook or email, though they look wonderful on my android phone, once sent they look terrible, washed out, bland and so on. I recall dimly that when I first got the phone, I could select the size or something on those lines of those photos, now i cannot. I have tried settings, I have tried everything I could think of (at least for a not very techno astute girl), and still no luck. Where should I look? How can I fix this. Please help.

Comment: Where are you looking at the photos when they look bland? Is it on the same phone, on your PC, or somewhere else? Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are taking the photos at full resolution from the camera and also that compression after uploading isn't enabled.

To be absolutely sure upload few photos on Dropbox and view them on PC. Check it's resolution on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

The Galaxy SIII has a better display than typical computer monitors.  It has a wider [color gamut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_gamut), which basically means it can accurately display more colors.  Without [color management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management) of some kind, to convert between the color spaces of different output devices, you will get the washed out look on displays with a smaller gamut.  It's a double-edged sword, as pictures optimized for smaller gamuts will look over-saturated on the SIII.  That's a common complaint among SIII reviewers.

There are apps for doing color management, but I haven't personally tried any of them.  Another option is to do the conversion on a desktop application, like photoshop.